# How to deactivate the bold text between <strong> tags in gVim?

Tags: vim

Every time I surround text between  tags the words become bold. I don't like having bold text in gVim so I was wondering how to deactivate that?

PS: I don't have any single bold attribute in my vim scheme:

```
set background=light

hi clear

if exists("syntax_on")
  syntax reset
endif

let colors_name = "_vs"


" Vim >= 7.0 specific colors
if version >= 700
  hi CursorLine guibg=#DDDDDD gui=none
  hi CursorColumn guibg=#EEEEEE gui=none
  hi MatchParen guifg=#f6f3e8 guibg=#857b6f gui=none
  hi Pmenu      guifg=#DDDDDD guibg=#666666 gui=none
  hi PmenuSel   guifg=#EEEEEE guibg=#444444 gui=none
endif

" General colors
hi Cursor       guifg=NONE    guibg=#888888 gui=none
hi Normal       guifg=#000000 guibg=#FFFFFF gui=none
hi NonText      guifg=#808080 guibg=#FFFFFF gui=none
hi LineNr       guifg=#FFFFFF guibg=#BBBBBB gui=none
hi StatusLine   guifg=#000000 guibg=#DDDDDD gui=none
hi StatusLineNC guifg=#857b6f guibg=#DDDDDD gui=none
hi VertSplit    guifg=#DDDDDD guibg=#DDDDDD gui=none
hi Folded       guibg=#AAAAAA guifg=#FFFFFF gui=none
hi Title        guifg=#000000 guibg=NONE    gui=none
hi Visual       guifg=NONE guibg=#DDDDDD gui=none
hi SpecialKey   guifg=#808080 guibg=#FFFFFF gui=none

" Syntax highlighting
hi Comment      guifg=#777777 gui=none
hi Todo         guifg=#8f8f8f gui=none
hi Constant     guifg=#e5786d gui=none
hi String       guifg=#2902FC gui=none
hi Identifier   guifg=#2902FC gui=none
hi Function     guifg=#2902FC gui=none
hi Type         guifg=#EF2811 gui=none
hi Statement    guifg=#9A1102 gui=none
hi Keyword      guifg=#9A1102 gui=none
hi PreProc      guifg=#2902FC gui=none
hi Number       guifg=#2902FC gui=none
hi Special      guifg=#2902FC gui=none

" Bottom
hi Question guifg=white gui=none
hi Question ctermfg=white term=none
hi ModeMsg  guifg=white gui=none

" Specific
hi cssIdentifier   guifg=#9A1102 gui=none
hi htmlTag         guifg=#2902FC gui=none
```

Answer (score 1):

Syntax highlighting of a text enclosed in `<b>` or `<strong>` tags (depending
on surrounding tags) is defined by one of the following highlighting groups.
(The below listing is an excerpt from the output of the `:highlight` command
for default color scheme.)

```
htmlBoldUnderline       xxx term=bold,underline cterm=bold,underline gui=bold,underline
htmlBoldItalic          xxx term=bold,italic cterm=bold,italic gui=bold,italic
htmlBold                xxx term=bold cterm=bold gui=bold
htmlBoldUnderlineItalic xxx term=bold,underline,italic cterm=bold,underline,italic gui=bold,underline,italic
htmlBoldItalicUnderline xxx links to htmlBoldUnderlineItalic
htmlUnderlineBold       xxx links to htmlBoldUnderline
htmlUnderlineBoldItalic xxx links to htmlBoldUnderlineItalic
htmlUnderlineItalicBold xxx links to htmlBoldUnderlineItalic
htmlItalicBold          xxx links to htmlBoldItalic
htmlItalicBoldUnderline xxx links to htmlBoldUnderlineItalic
htmlItalicUnderlineBold xxx links to htmlBoldUnderlineItalic
```

To change highlighting for this groups, redefine them in your color scheme
without `bold` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Put `let html_my_rendering=1` or `let html_no_rendering=1` to your `.vimrc` might did it.